# ubuntu 20.04 share folder with non-ascii filenames

Tags: 20.04, file-sharing, filename

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new machine. I'm trying to share my external drive with non-ascii file names. I get:

```
'net usershare' returned error 255: [2023/04/30 09:30:13,  0] ../../lib/util/debug.c:1100(reopen_one_log)
  reopen_one_log: Unable to open new log file 'Быков Дмитрий/log.net': No such file or directory
net usershare add: share name /media/alex/sg8t/mp3/books/rus/быков дмитрий contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/\+=;:",)
```

Here is the sharing window screenshot.

[image]

It used to work with previous versions. What is the problem?

Comment: use " around the name and it will work BUT it would be better to use only ascii

Comment: Sorry, but none of these suggestions work:  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b4ZNgqWofJqVGyerKcuk41HHGzQaAzSZ/view?usp=share_link 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bn1iN01qfiMxrfDLbI-X6Rda3qpKHFe5/view?usp=share_link